# PostgreSQL: Unable to drop a specific table named "user"

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm unable to delete a specific table in my PostgreSQL database. That table is called "user". When I try to run the snippet of code below,

```
    import psycopg2
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydatabase' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='mypassword'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE user;")  
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

It spits out the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "dev_psycog.py", line 20, in <module>
       cur.execute("DROP TABLE user;")  
  psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "user"
  LINE 1: DROP TABLE user;
```

I can delete any other table in my database just fine, but I can't seem to delete my table called "user". Is it because "user" is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)?

Comment: Try `drop table 'user'`

Comment: So I got a similar error when I wrapped it single quotes. But it worked when i wrapped it with double quotes. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote "user" as below

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydatabase' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='mypassword'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE "user";')  
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
>   quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
>   characters in double-quotes (").

Comment: Wrapping user with double quotes did the trick. Single quotes still gives the same error that I encountered. Thank you

Comment: @user3635123 accept as answer if it solved your problem